# Shaded/Repackaged jar as a dependency

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, maven-shade-plugin

We have a situation where we need one application to be able to connect to to two versions of kafka(0.7.2 and 0.10.0+) and act as a router. I'm trying to omit using two runtimes here as we need this to be stupid fast, so want to prevent additional serialization/deserialization when sending data between runtimes.

To do this, i've tryied to repackage the old kafka driver from package ***kafka*** to ***old.kafka*** like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>kafka-router</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.deer</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>old-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <kafka.version>0.7.2</kafka.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
                                    <version>${kafka.version}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                                    <includes>**/*.class,**/*.xml</includes>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <includes>**/*.java</includes>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>kafka.</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>old.kafka.</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm using dependency plugin to unpack kafka classes to target/classes & shade plugin to repackage them. The reason for this is that the final jar should act as if it is a kafka driver jar(it has no other transitive dependencies, therefore it can't cause some mismatch using ***kafka*** instead of ***old.kafka***. But that's not really the point here, just trying to prevent out-of-topic questions.

The main problem here is that when i look at the jar that has been installed to .m2, it looks correct(having the ***old.kafka*** package):

[image]

But when i try to use this jar as dependency like so ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>kafka-router</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.deer</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>router-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deer</groupId>
            <artifactId>old-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

... and reference it in a class like so ...

```
package org.deer.test;

import old.kafka.producer.ProducerData;

public class TwoKafkaDriversExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProducerData();
    }
}
```

... the import it self is not working. I have a suspicion that the shaded jar is missing something maven-related, but haven't noticed anything. Another possible though is that shade plugin or asm doesn't like the bytecode that scala classes are generating.

[image: Import not working]

[image: Project view]

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Could you add the error message from the command line to your question?

Comment: What IDE are you using and how does your classpath look like?

Comment: What happens when you run `mvn install` in the command line in your new project, it might be that your IDE does not understand the translated classes

Comment: Have you tried it without the -SNAPSHOT?

Comment: How do you have an bounty of 300 reputation when you only have 143 reputation@ján Srincek

Comment: @Programmer i've had more, before the bounty setting :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so i've been able to figure this out. The import error is a problem with intelij, for some reason it doesn't see the repackaged classes. But the maven does, with using correct constructor and adding scala-lang dependency(it was complaining about missing Seq class) i was able to build this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Full example uploaded on github - https://github.com/Marssmart/kafka-router

Comment: Intelij not picking up shaded dependencies seems to be a known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93855

Comment: Did you reload the maven project after your changes?